# WebdriverIO typescript mocha to get last similar classname on a table <tr><td>

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, webdriver-io, pageobjects, webautomation

I need to get the last classname data, the number of classname is dynamic, so the number of classname cannot be determined and it always change every time i run the automation, but I just need to get the last classname data. Need your help guys, thanks

```
<tbody>
 <tr>
   <td class="classnameData"> mydata1@here </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td class="classnameData"> mydata2@here </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td class="classnameData"> mydata3@here </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td class="classnameData"> mydata4@here </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>...</tr>
 <tr>...</tr>
 <tr>...</tr>
 <tr>
    <td class="classnameData"> mydata8@here </td>
 </tr>
```

how can i get tha last classname?
tried it on a page object, its showing an error on **.[last()]**, **.last()** , **.[-1]** and others mentioned below

**pageObject.ts**
tried both of this

```
get tableData_last() { return  $(".classnameData").[last()]}
get tableData_last() { return  $(".classnameData").last()}
```

and tried using [-1] , :last-of-type and :nth-child(-1) they all returned undefined

```
get tableData_last() { return  $(".classnameData")[-1]}
get tableData_last() { return  $(".classnameData:last-of-type")}
get tableData_last() { return  $(".classnameData:nth-child(-1)")}
```

and will not be able to check on my *it* method

```
await expect(pageObject.tableData_last).toHaveTextContaining(TESTDATA.DATA);
```

Comment: Try `.classnameData:nth-child(-1)`

Comment: "Received: undefined" that's what it received and show using .classnameData:nth-child(-1)

Comment: https://webdriver.io/docs/selectors/#chain-selectors says webdriverIO supports nth-child selector. Im curious if `.classnameData:nth-child(1)` or  `$(".classnameData")` itself works for you?

Comment: **.classnameData:nth-child(1)** works, it pick up the first row data, but i need the last row, the **.classnameData:nth-child(-1)** returns undefined

Comment: What about classnameData:nth-last-child(1)?

Comment: classnameData:nth-last-child(1) also returns undefined

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty straight forward using vanilla JS. We can retrieve all the elements by className and then pick the last one.

```
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('classNameData');
let lastElement = elements[elements.length - 1] as HTMLElement;
let lastElementText = lastElement.innerText;
```

Comment: hovering on the innerText, shows a error **"Property 'innerText' does not exist on type 'Element'. ts(2339)"**

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly. Please have a look at it.

Comment: still does not work. it shows a error **"ReferenceError: document is not defined"**

Answer (score 0):

You are already there, check out the snippet!

```js
const ele = $("tbody .classnameData").last();
console.log("Last element text is: ", ele.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="classnameData">mydata1@here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="classnameData">mydata2@here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="classnameData">mydata3@here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="classnameData">mydata4@here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="classnameData">mydata8@here</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```